# What is “ptymonitor” seen in the Linux system logs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I see "kernel: ptymonitor[8742]: segfault at" in the var logs ... what does "ptymonitor" mean? I don't see any online resources to provide an answer.

Comment: Please provide the full error messages for that PID around the time of the event, and which operating system distro you run.  A crash dump may have been captured, but where it is depends on your OS.

Comment: What is "ptymonitor" ?